# Approximately solving the transcendental equation $\tan(N z)=-i\sin(z)$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, roots, transcendental-equations

everyone!

I want to find a simple analytical formula for the solutions of the following transcendental equation:
$$ \tan(N z) = -i\sin(z), $$
where $N>1$ is an integer, $z$ is the complex variable restricted to the range $0\le \text{Re}(z)\le\pi$. I can visualize the function $\log_{10}\left| \tan(Nz)+i\sin(z) \right|$ on the complex plane, see it below for $N=20$:

[image]

Clearly, there are $N$ solutions in the defined range that correspond to green/blue regions. I found in some article that the solution to this equation for the case $N \gg 1$, $z \ll 1$ or $\pi-z \ll 1$ can be written as follows: $z_k = \frac{k\pi}{N} - i \min(k, N-k) \frac{k \pi}{N^2}$, they are specified by black circles.

Indeed, as one can see, these are nice approximations for the roots far enough from the $\text{Re}(z) \sim \pi/2$ region, but close to $\text{Re}(z) \sim \pi/2$ it completely fails to describe those $2$ roots right in the center of the picture. Can anybody give me an advice how to write a kind of perturbation theory for this case, what one has to do? I am just not that experienced at analytically writing solutions to transcendental equations, usually I just solve them numerically.

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE OF 06.08.2021:**
So, I contacted one of the authors who wrote the original approximate solution working far away from $\text{Re}[z]\approx \pi/2$ point, it was obtained using the following rationale:

1. Consider $z \ll 1$, then the zero-order solution can be obtained by considering $\tan(Nz)=0$, so $z^{(0)}=j \pi/N$, where $j = 1,2,\ldots,N$.
2. Now consider the first-order approximation, in order to do that, expand $\sin(z) \approx z$, the solution of $\tan(N z) \approx -i z$ for small $z \ll 1$ is known approximately as $N z^{(1)} \approx \pi j - i z^{(0)}$, where $j = 1,2,\ldots,N$.
3. After that one has to replace the right hand side $z^{(0)}$ with it's zero order approximation from 1).
4. Repeat the same procedure for the case $|z-\pi| \ll 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the functions
$$f(n,a,b)=\tan (n (a+i b))+i \sin (a+i b)$$
$$F(n,a,b)= \Re\Big[f[n, a, b]\Big]^2+\Im\Big[f[n, a, b]\Big]^2 $$ For a given integer value of $n$, the contour plot of $F(n,a,b)$ shows what you observed.

For $a=\frac \pi 2$, we need to solve for $b$
$$\sinh (2 b n)+\cosh (b) \left(\cosh (2 b n)+(-1)^n\right)=0$$

For sure $b=0$ is a trivial solution for  $n=2m-1$. But there is another one which is the solution of
$$\cosh (b) \tanh ((2 m-1)b)+1=0$$

Assuming $b$ to be small, the Taylor expansion is
$$g(b)=\cosh (b) \tanh ((2 m-1)b)+1=1+b (2 m-1)+O\left(b^3\right)$$ So, a first guess is $b_0=-\frac 1{2m-1}$ which is good since $g(b_0)\times g''(b_0) >0$; so, by Darboux theorem, Newton method will converge without any overshoot to the solution.  For example, for $m=5$, $b_0=-\frac 19$ Newton iterates are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & b_k \\
 0 & -0.111111 \\
 1 & -0.171220 \\
 2 & -0.215223 \\
 3 & -0.234746 \\
 4 & -0.237307 \\
 5 & -0.237342
\end{array}
\right)$$

However, a very simple and rather accurate approximation is $${\color{red}{b_m^{(1)}\sim -\frac{1}{(2 m-1)^{2/3}}}} \tag 1$$

Another possible approximation could be obtained writing
$$2m-1=-\frac{\tanh ^{-1}(\text{sech}(b))}{b}$$ Expanding the rhs as Taylor series around $b=0$ would lead, after reversion, to
$${\color{red}{b_m^{(2)}\sim -\frac{W(2 (2 m-1))}{2 m-1}}} \tag 2$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.

If you can use Lambert function, use $b_m^{(2)}$ as a starting guess for Newton method since
$$g\left(b_m^{(2)}\right)\times g''\left(b_m^{(2)}\right)>0\quad \text{while} \quad g\left(b_m^{(1)}\right)\times g''\left(b_m^{(1)}\right)<0 \quad \text{if} \quad m>10$$ and moreover, it is a better estimate.

As a function of $m$, the first solutions $b_m$ are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 m & b_m^{(1)} & b_m^{(2)} & \text{solution} \\
 2 & -0.480750 & -0.477468 &  -0.481212 \\
 3 & -0.341995 & -0.349106 &  -0.350398 \\
 4 & -0.273276 & -0.280578 &  -0.281200 \\
 5 & -0.231120 & -0.236988 &  -0.237342 \\
 6 & -0.202180 & -0.206443 &  -0.206667 \\
 7 & -0.180872 & -0.183673 &  -0.183825 \\
 8 & -0.164414 & -0.165948 &  -0.166058 \\
 9 & -0.151252 & -0.151704 &  -0.151785 \\
 10 & -0.140442 & -0.139972 &  -0.140034 \\
 11 & -0.131377 & -0.130117 &  -0.130167 \\
 12 & -0.123646 & -0.121708 &  -0.121747 \\
 13 & -0.116961 & -0.114436 &  -0.114468 \\
 14 & -0.111111 & -0.108076 &  -0.108103 \\
 15 & -0.105942 & -0.102462 &  -0.102485 \\
 16 & -0.101335 & -0.097465 &  -0.097484 \\
 17 & -0.097198 & -0.092984 &  -0.093001 \\
 18 & -0.093459 & -0.088941 &  -0.088955 \\
 19 & -0.090060 & -0.085272 &  -0.085284 \\
 20 & -0.086954 & -0.081926 &  -0.081936
\end{array}
\right)$$

When $m$ is large,
$$1-\cosh \left(\frac{1}{(2 m-1)^{2/3}}\right) \tanh \left(\sqrt[3]{2 m-1}\right)\sim 1-\cosh \left(\frac{1}{(2 m-1)^{2/3}}\right)$$ and, by Taylor, this is
$$\sim -\frac 1{3m\sqrt[3]{16 m}} \left(1+\frac 2 {3m}+\cdots \right)$$

But, if $n=2m$ there is no root at all for
$$\cosh (b)+\tanh (2 b m)=0$$

Comment: Dear @Claude Leibovici, thank you for your answer! You are absolutely right: only if $N$ is odd, then there is a root with the real part being exactly $\pi/2$, but what I meant in my question is to expand the functions near $z \approx \left( \frac{\pi}{2} + \delta z' \right) + i z''$, and then, from some rationale, find approximately $\delta z', z''$. So, for even $N$ there are $2$ symmetrically shifted roots (like in the original figure), while for odd $N$ there is a single root with $\delta z'=0$.

Comment: Dear @Claude Leibovici, is there any way to somehow approximately write an explicit solution to the last line of yours? In a form like $b \approx f(m)$.

Comment: @Sl0wp0k3. Just wait. I am working precisely this point.

Comment: Dear @Claude Leibovici, thank you for such a detailed answer! Your $b^{(2)}_m$ solution looks great! I need to somehow generalize it for even $N$ so that I could find the two roots close to $z'\approx \pi/2$. During that time, I have tried to expand in Taylor series, and considered the lowest non-vanishing order, but the obtained solution failed completely.

However, I have a question: whether there are any general strategies to solve transcendental equations analytically that one can start from?

Comment: @Sl0wp0k3. I did the same and guess what ? I failed ! Back to the problem, I have been amazed to be able to introduce here Lambert function (my love for 64+ years - don't tell it to my wife). Cheers :-)

Comment: the appearance of Lambert function is, indeed, a little surprising here. The only situation I encountered it in physics is non-Markovian dynamics of quantum systems :).

Comment: Another interesting question is how exactly the guys obtained the approximate answer for all $N$ roots I posted in the original question: in their article they do not elaborate a lot on that. :) I might contact one of the authors at some time to gain some insight, and mb will post it as an update to the question.

Comment: @Sl0wp0k3. Yes, do it ! Where is the paper ?

Comment: here it is: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1134/1.1187364  Eq. (16), (17). The second author used to be my lecturer during the bachelor/masters. Probably, will discuss it with him.

Comment: Dear @Claude Leibovici, I have the last question: was your $b^{(1)}$ solution just a good guess or you somehow derived it? 
Moreover, I added few lines on how the original solution was obtained by the authors.

Comment: @Sl0wp0k3. SInce I follow this question I saw your edits. For $b^{(1)}_m$ it came from a look at the first numbers plus a quick and dirty regression. Nothing more. Cheers :-)

Comment: I wasted some time on trying to solve the even $N$ case, but it turns out to be hard :(. The trick originally used to build a kind of perturbation theory outside of $z\approx \pi/2$ region does not work here: $0$ order approximate equation does not have solutions at all, while the next approximation is already a fairly complicated system of $2$ coupled transcendental equations. Fun fact: they have derived the lambert w function using a completely different rationale in that paper by Vladimirova, Ivchenko, Kavokin. You can find it in the end.

Comment: @Sl0wp0k3. Headaches + nightmares : are these your gifts to the old man ? Back to serious : I cannot access the paper. I work this problem almost every day and I am just becoming crazy.

Comment: haha, Claude Leibovici, use sci-hub :)